# NSData init?(contentsOf url: URL) migration from Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2

New to iOS/Swift. I am trying to migrate a project (that simply fetches contents from a URL via the `NSData init()` method) from Swift 2 to Swift 3. The original code looks like this:

```
let loadedImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if imageURL == user.profileImageURL {
                    if let imageData = loadedImageData  {
                        self.profileImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Swift 3 migration:

```
 let loadedImageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL as URL)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if imageURL == user.profileImageURL {
                    if let imageData = loadedImageData  {
                        self.profileImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am not sure as to why we need to cast the `NSData` return value as a `URL` and then cast that return again to a `Data` type while loading the image within Swift 3. We are assigning the raw data to a variable `loadedImageData` in both the version. Why the casting then? It seems that the `UIImage init()` method needs a data object within Swift 3. However for Swift 2 there is no casting for the same. Why is that?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The migration consists of some changes in those methods' signatures, namely, the types they accept.

In Swift 2, `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` and `UIImage(data:)` take `NSURL` and `NSData`, respectively.

Currently, they have been changed to `NSData(contentsOf:)` and `UIImage(data:)` that accept, respectively, `URL` (`struct`) and `Data` (instead of `NSData`); as a result, the casts are necessary unless you constructed your URL from type `URL` instead of `NSURL`.

You could use, instead, `Data(contentsOf: URL)` to avoid the cast as well.

Comment: ahhh i see...the URL is actually being built as an optional NSUrl variable..that does make sense. Where can we find the documentation for swift 2.0 API' s and the respective changes. I am referring this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata. But this doesn't show the changes for the init method from 2.0 to 3.0. Thanks!!